# How to scroll all the way down the page?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, scroll

i go to a url of a tweet and it has a lot of comments down there!! And here are my 2 pieces of code I've tried.

With the code 1, it scrolls down to the end of the page, but because the pull down is too large and the element is not found.

With the code 2, I changed it to scroll down slowly with 1000 but it only scrolled down a few times and then stopped, I checked and python said it had scrolled all the way down the page . I tried changing the parameter but it only scrolls a few times .

code 1 :

```
`while True:
                last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
                driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
                time.sleep(2)
                new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
                try:
                    elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,
                                                    "//a[@class='css-4rbku5 css-18t94o4 css-901oao r-14j79pv r-1loqt21 r-xoduu5 r-1q142lx r-1w6e6rj r-37j5jr r-a023e6 r-16dba41 r-9aw3ui r-rjixqe r-bcqeeo r-3s2u2q r-qvutc0']")                   
                    click4 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                                 "//div[@class='css-1dbjc4n r-16y2uox r-1wbh5a2 r-1777fci']")
                    click4.click()
                except:
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                try:
                    elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,
                                                    "//a[@class='css-4rbku5 css-18t94o4 css-901oao r-14j79pv r-1loqt21 r-xoduu5 r-1q142lx r-1w6e6rj r-37j5jr r-a023e6 r-16dba41 r-9aw3ui r-rjixqe r-bcqeeo r-3s2u2q r-qvutc0']")
                    click5 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='css-1dbjc4n r-1ndi9ce']")
                    click5.click()
                except:
                    time.sleep(0.5)


                if new_height == last_height:
                    print("end")
                    time.sleep(10)  
                    break`
```

code 2:

```
while True:
                last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
                driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 1000)", "")
                time.sleep(2)
                new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
                try:
                    elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,
                                                    "//a[@class='css-4rbku5 css-18t94o4 css-901oao r-14j79pv r-1loqt21 r-xoduu5 r-1q142lx r-1w6e6rj r-37j5jr r-a023e6 r-16dba41 r-9aw3ui r-rjixqe r-bcqeeo r-3s2u2q r-qvutc0']")                   
                    click4 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                                 "//div[@class='css-1dbjc4n r-16y2uox r-1wbh5a2 r-1777fci']")
                    click4.click()
                except:
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                try:
                    elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,
                                                    "//a[@class='css-4rbku5 css-18t94o4 css-901oao r-14j79pv r-1loqt21 r-xoduu5 r-1q142lx r-1w6e6rj r-37j5jr r-a023e6 r-16dba41 r-9aw3ui r-rjixqe r-bcqeeo r-3s2u2q r-qvutc0']")
                    click5 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='css-1dbjc4n r-1ndi9ce']")
                    click5.click()
                except:
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                if new_height == last_height:
                    print("end")
                    time.sleep(10)  
                    break
```

i tried many times but it doesn't work , hope someone help me find the problem . Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide HTML structure / resource, so we could help you?

Comment: it's just a tweet similar to this: [link](https://twitter.com/profit8lue/status/1685479164609257473)  @Yaroslavm

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use the Twitter API for this? Many web sites disallow scraping and may have mechanisms in place to prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this on frontend, I have solution for you.

```js
wdwait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
last_height = driver.execute_script("return window.pageYOffset")
driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 1000)", "")
driver.execute_script("function waitForValueNotToStopChanging(valueGetter, interval) {return new Promise((resolve) => {let previousValue = valueGetter();let unchangedCount = 0;const intervalId = setInterval(() => {const currentValue = valueGetter();if (currentValue === previousValue) {unchangedCount++;} else {unchangedCount = 0;}if (unchangedCount >= 2) {clearInterval(intervalId);resolve(currentValue);}previousValue = currentValue;}, interval);});}let scrollHeightGetter = () => document.body.scrollHeight; await waitForValueNotToStopChanging(scrollHeightGetter, 500);")
wdwait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[role=progressbar]")))
new_height = driver.execute_script("return window.pageYOffset")
```

This is lines you should use in code 2 after `while` and before `try`.

1. First of all, I changed condition to `window.pageYOffset` as far as it is more stable (changes directly after any move).
2. Except implicit wait I check that scrollHeight wasn't changed within 2 timeframes (1 second or more), so you can be sure that scroll is happened.
3. I wait for new tweets loader to be invisible (it can appear after scroll + stable position)
4. Only then I get `window.pageYOffset` again

I tested on tweet you provided and successfully scrolled to bottom.

Here is js function I used (but you can change condition from `document.body.scrollHeight` to `window.pageYOffset`, for example

```js
function waitForValueNotToStopChanging(valueGetter, interval) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    let previousValue = valueGetter();
    let unchangedCount = 0;

    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      const currentValue = valueGetter();

      if (currentValue === previousValue) {
        unchangedCount++;
      } else {
        unchangedCount = 0;
      }

      if (unchangedCount >= 2) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        resolve(currentValue);
      }

      previousValue = currentValue;
    }, interval);
  });
}

let scrollHeightGetter = () => document.body.scrollHeight;

await waitForValueNotToStopChanging(scrollHeightGetter, 500)
```

Comment: thanks for your help , i am not good at frontend !! I will learn more !! @Yaroslavm

Comment: @Venus np. Try it - if it works for you, can you mark this answer as correct, plz? :)